# How to use a variable as a dictionary key?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

```
coming_monday = today + datetime.timedelta(days=-today.weekday(), weeks=1)
month = coming_monday.strftime("%B")
collection = db['empmain']
record = collection.find_one({'Availablity.<want to pass in the month variable here'})
```

format of the collection:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBMpY.png)

Comment: Are you asking for this `{'Availablity.{}'.format(month)}`?

Comment: `x = 12 collection.find_one({'x':x})`

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks! That works, I completely forgot about the format method. Thanks again! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example worked for me:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
mydict = {a : "a_", b : "b_", c : "c_"}
```

I've declard some variables with some values as above.

```
>>> mydict[1]
'a_'
>>> mydict[b]
'b_'
```

I was able to access values in the dictionary using both the variable names or the values.

Comment: You should not use `dict` as a variable name. It is a saved keyword in Python.